# Extra branch in Tkinter Popup Menu

Tags: python, tkinter

> This is my current warehouse program.

[image: My current program]

> Can I make my popup menu look like this with extra branches:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly you can. Just add sub menus to your original menu.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def popup(event):
    rmenu = tk.Menu(None, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)
    sub_menu = tk.Menu(None, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)

    for txt in ("command1","command2"):
        rmenu.add_command(label=txt, compound="left")

    rmenu.add_cascade(label="Sub menu", menu=sub_menu)

    for txt in ("command3","command4"):
        sub_menu.add_command(label=txt, compound="left")

    rmenu.tk_popup(event.x_root + 40, event.y_root + 10, entry="0")

root.bind("<Button-3>",popup)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The answer I was looking for, Thanks.